# Jquery Datatable not reading ajax data from json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

I am creating some mockups using dummy data. I have to show some data, which I have stored in a `.json` file as of now, in `jquery datatable` using `ajax`. I have gone through the [examples](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) in `Datatables site` but the data doesn't show up. May be its not reading the data correctly or at all. Have tried a lot of workarounds but nothing seems to be working.

The folder structure is as follows:

[image]

My HTML code is in file `backlog.html`. It goes like this:

```
<table id="backlogTable" class="grid">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th nowrap="nowrap" width="230px">Hotel Name One</th>
                    <th nowrap="nowrap" width="110px">Hotel Price One</th>
                    <th nowrap="nowrap" width="230px">Hotel Name Two</th>
                    <th nowrap="nowrap" width="110px">Hotel Price Two</th>
                    <th nowrap="nowrap" width="230px">Hotel Name Three</th>
                    <th nowrap="nowrap" width="110px">Hotel Price Three</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

The script is written inside html file only. The javascript code is:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

$("#loading").ajaxStart(function () {
    $(this).show();
});

$("#loading").ajaxStop(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});

$.ajax(
         {              
                type            : "GET",
                url             : "resources/LasVegas.json",
                contentType     : 'application/json',
                dataType        : 'json',
                success         : function(json)
                {                  
                    oTable = $("#backlogTable").dataTable({
                        "aaData"            :   json.aaData,
                        "bProcessing"       : true,
                        "sPaginationType"   : "full_numbers",
                        "bJQueryUI"         : true,
                        "bRetrieve"         : true,
                        "bPaginate"         : true,
                        "bStateSave"        : true,
                        "scrollY"           : 200,
                        "scrollCollapse"    : true,
                        "jQueryUI"          : true,
                        "bSort"             : true,
                        "iDisplayLength"    : 10,
                        "oLanguage": {
                                        "sProcessing": "<img src='resources/images/loader.gif'/>",
                                        "sEmptyTable": "No records found."
                                     },
                        "aoColumns": [
                                            { "sClass": "left"},
                                            { "sClass": "left"},
                                            { "sClass": "left"},
                                            { "sClass": "left"},
                                            { "sClass": "left"},
                                            { "sClass": "left"}
                                      ],
                        "error": function() {
                                  alert("Failed to load Data");
                                 }
                    });
                }

          }
    );
    });
```

When I try to open the HTML file in browser, only the table headers are shown and nothing else. No data, not even the empty table message. When I check the browser console, it says

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/vshukla/Pictures/Mockups/html/resources/LasVegas.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

following is the `LasVegas.json` data:

```
    {
  "aaData": [
                    [
                         "Wynn Las Vegas",
                         "$151",
                         "Caesers Las Vegas",
                         "$239.00",
                         "Flamingo Las Vegas",
                         "$151"
                    ],
                    [
                         "The Palazzo",
                         "$159",
                         "The Palazzo Resort Hotel Casino",
                         "$249.00",
                         "The Balazio Resort",
                         "$159"
                    ],
                    [
                         "Encore at Wynn Las Vegas",
                         "$151",
                         "Wynn Las Vegas",
                         "$359.00",
                         "Hotel Las Vegas",
                         "$151"
                    ],
                    [
                         "Caesars Palace",
                         "$229",
                         "Flamingo Bay",
                         "$219.00",
                         "Caesars Palace & Resort",
                         "$229"
                    ]
    ]
    }
```

please help.

Comment: This is happening because its being treated as a cross-domain request.  Try to access the file from localhost e.g. localhost/resources/LasVegas.json

Comment: Ok. So now used localhost. Json data is coming in response but now, the table shows "No Records Found". Whats wrong?

Comment: @markpsmith, I reproduced the above code with the same directory structure, no changes in the code at all -  _and it works right away_!

Comment: @roger_that, Your code works fine here. I have tested with dataTables 1.10.4.  You are probably not running your code from within a server (like `http://localhost`) `file://` will fail. So it is not the code, but how you run it.

Comment: @davidkonrad - I'm assuming from the syntax that he's using v1.9.

Comment: @markpsmith - it works with no problems for dataTables 1.9.0 and above.  If you go lower, 1.8,2, it still loads the JSON, but strange things happends with the search box being undefined and so on.

Comment: @davidkonrad yeah. Got it. Have fixed the issue with how I was running the code :)